# Create new column in a view with transformation

Tags: oracle

I have data like this in my table `tab1`:

```
int_ref  ant_ref  counter  type23  pol_ref  pol_flag      sale  share      prof
cse_123  cse_237  abc_123  as               NC        375361.4     34  374037.4
cse_124  cse_237  abc_123  as      cos_345  C         65760.86     54  64436.86
cse_124  cse_237  abc_123  as      cos_345  C            14250     34  12926
cse_124  cse_237  abc_123  as               NC        44099.79     22  42775.79
cse_435  cse_456  abc_123  as               NC           20000     13  18676
cse_237           abc_123  of               NC        497096.8     57  495772.8
cse_456           abc_123  of      cos_235  C          8760.79     12  7436.79
cse_456           abc_123  of               NC         1000000     71  998676
cse_263           abc_123  of               NC            7000     23  5676
cse_544           abc_123  of      cos_423  C             3424     32  44533
```

I have totally 5 views that are built on this table.

- 1st view (view1) is to extract and transform the data in the required format to be used in other views.
- 2nd view (view2) is the unpivot of the FL values from the 1st view and group by of 1st view.
- 3rd, 4th, 5th views (view3/view4/view5) are secondary views that use the data from 2nd view.

Now I am looking to create ‘new column’ flag in  my 1st view (view1).

For same `int_ref` value where `pol_flag` has both (‘C’ and ‘NC’) or just ‘C’ alone then ‘new column’ should show as ‘T’, otherwise ‘F’.

No group by, sum or any other window function etc are allowed.

My `view1` is something like (about 3000 lines):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW VIEW1 AS
Select 
Col1,
fl,
number of case statements,
,,,,,,,,,,
New_column(required with the flag)
From tab1
Join tabxyz ...
```

Output of `view1`:

```
int_ref  counter  pol_flag       sale  Fl    new_column
cse_123  abc_123  NC        475757584  R510  F 
cse_124  abc_123  C            477478  R530  T 
cse_124  abc_123  C          75678489  R530  T 
cse_124  abc_123  NC          9867589  R520  T 
cse_435  abc_123  NC            86548  R530  F 
cse_237  abc_123  NC          8367444  R540  F 
cse_456  abc_123  C           8760.79  R550  T 
cse_456  abc_123  NC            46547  R560  T
```

Comment: Why the restriction on "group by, sum or any other window function"? Sounds like you could do what you're after with a couple of analytic functions. Also, is this MySQL or Oracle? You mention Oracle in the title of your post, but you've tagged both. Which one is it?

Comment: @Boneist Hi it is Oracle. I cant use them as thats how the view is designed  and it has too many transformations.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do this with an analytic function and a case statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW VIEW1 AS
Select 
Col1,
fl,
number of case statements,
...
case when max(case when pol_flag = 'C' then 'C') over (partition by int_ref) = 'C' then 'T' else 'F' end new_column
From tab1
Joins tabxyz …….
```

Comment: Thanks @Boneist... I used analytical count function for this... case when count (distinct pol_flag) over (partition by int_ref) > 1 then 'T' else 'F' end as new_column